# Format price in euros currency using Angular Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to display a price in euros with no fraction and a dot every 3 digits.

So the price 12350,30 would become 12.350 €.

I tried to solve this with the currency filter but I was only able to make it work with USD. I then tried the following:

```
<span data-ng-bind="property.price | number:0"></span>
```

But I get a comma every 3 digits instead of a dot.

And I am not able to add the € sign at the end.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: @Miguel I wonder if the thouands seprator (dot instead of comma) is a locale issue, e.g. set by the users preferences, either way, you can find a few blog posts on the web on how to make a custom filter to deal with this if you need to

Comment: As said it depends on your locale settings, just change that and you get correct separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I am not able to add the € sign at the end.

You can specify the currency symbol

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

So

```
<span data-ng-bind="property.price | currency:"€":2></span>
```

> But I get a comma every 3 digits instead of a dot.

The decimal and group seperator depends on the locale, here a relevant part from AngularJS source code

```
  "NUMBER_FORMATS": {
    "CURRENCY_SYM": "\u20ac",
    "DECIMAL_SEP": ",",
    "GROUP_SEP": "\u00a0",
```

Source is the french (fr-fr) locale for AngularJS, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_fr-fr.js#L78

Answer (score 1):

Miguel,

You can create a custom filter:

```
app.filter('toEuros', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Number(input).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 0}) + ' €';
  };
});
```

and then use as:

```
<span data-ng-bind="property.price | toEuros"></span>
```

(for some reason the language pt-PT puts spaces instead of `.` as thousands separator)